# jQuery sortable enable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm disabling dragging on jquery sortable list but not sure how to enable it back, can someone point me in direction please,

```
$(".anotherClass").sortable('disable'); //it disables it
```

I can't seem to find anything in documentation.

This question says enable input here but its not working

```
$("#wantedItems").sortable({
    receive: function (event, ui) {
        //enable the input here  which input ???????????????????????????????
    }
});
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to enable `$(".anotherClass").sortable()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just call it with 'enable'

```
$( ".selector" ).sortable( "enable" );
```

Documentation for method: http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-enable

Answer (score 1):

```
simply write.....

$(".anotherClass").sortable()
```

Answer (score 0):

**enable()**

Enables the sortable.

- This method does not accept any arguments.

**Code examples:**
Invoke the enable method:

```
$( ".selector" ).sortable( "enable" );
```

Link: http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-enable

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working. If you toggle between enable/disable, it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

To enable `sortable()` again you can use

`$(".anotherClass").sortable("enable");`

To toggle enable/disable on the click of a button with id `toggleButton`

```
$('#toggleButton').click(function() {
    //check if sortable() is enabled and change and change state accordingly
  // Getter
  var disabled = $(".anotherClass").sortable( "option", "disabled" );
  if (disabled) {
    $(".anotherClass").sortable( "enable" );
  }
  else {
    $(".anotherClass").sortable("disable");
  }
});
```